# What's the difference between the .width and .w attribute of a Pygame Rect object?

Tags: pygame, rect

The official [*pygame documentation*](http://www.pygame.org/docs/) states that there are several *virtual attributes* which can be used to move and align a `pygame.Rect` instance:

[image: Virtual Attributes of a PyGame Rect Object]

Until now **I used `myRect.w` respectively `myRect.h` to determine the width or height** of an `pygame.Rect` object. But to complete this graphic I came across the **`.width` and `.height` attributes**.

The interesting thing is that **both attributes seem to provide us the same date**, as you can see in following code listing:

```
>>> myRect = pygame.Rect((10, 20), (200,100)) #create a new Rect instance
>>> myRect.w
200
>>> myRect.width
200
>>> myRect.size
(200, 100)
```

*What´s now the difference between these two attribute pairs?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference. You can take a look at the [source](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/751b612df1d18c28e2811afd85021afeaa5048a5/src/rect.c?at=default#cl-1453) of the `Rect` class:

```
static PyGetSetDef rect_getsets[] = {
    { "x", (getter)rect_getleft, (setter)rect_setleft, NULL, NULL },
    { "y", (getter)rect_gettop, (setter)rect_settop, NULL, NULL },
    { "w", (getter)rect_getwidth, (setter)rect_setwidth, NULL, NULL },
    { "h", (getter)rect_getheight, (setter)rect_setheight, NULL, NULL },
    { "width", (getter)rect_getwidth, (setter)rect_setwidth, NULL, NULL },
    { "height", (getter)rect_getheight, (setter)rect_setheight, NULL, NULL },
    { "top", (getter)rect_gettop, (setter)rect_settop, NULL, NULL },
    { "left", (getter)rect_getleft, (setter)rect_setleft, NULL, NULL },
    { "bottom", (getter)rect_getbottom, (setter)rect_setbottom, NULL, NULL },
    { "right", (getter)rect_getright, (setter)rect_setright, NULL, NULL },
    { "centerx", (getter)rect_getcenterx, (setter)rect_setcenterx, NULL, NULL },
    { "centery", (getter)rect_getcentery, (setter)rect_setcentery, NULL, NULL },
    { "topleft", (getter)rect_gettopleft, (setter)rect_settopleft, NULL, NULL },
    { "topright", (getter)rect_gettopright, (setter)rect_settopright, NULL,
     NULL },
    { "bottomleft", (getter)rect_getbottomleft, (setter)rect_setbottomleft,
      NULL, NULL },
    { "bottomright", (getter)rect_getbottomright, (setter)rect_setbottomright,
      NULL, NULL },
    { "midtop", (getter)rect_getmidtop, (setter)rect_setmidtop, NULL, NULL },
    { "midleft", (getter)rect_getmidleft, (setter)rect_setmidleft, NULL, NULL },
    { "midbottom", (getter)rect_getmidbottom, (setter)rect_setmidbottom, NULL,
      NULL },
    { "midright", (getter)rect_getmidright, (setter)rect_setmidright, NULL,
      NULL },
    { "size", (getter)rect_getsize, (setter)rect_setsize, NULL, NULL },
    { "center", (getter)rect_getcenter, (setter)rect_setcenter, NULL, NULL },

    { "__safe_for_unpickling__", (getter)rect_getsafepickle, NULL, NULL, NULL },
    { NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL }  /* Sentinel */
};
```

You can see e.g. that both `w` and `width` call [`rect_getwidth`](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/751b612df1d18c28e2811afd85021afeaa5048a5/src/rect.c?at=default#cl-1077):

```
/*width*/
static PyObject*
rect_getwidth (PyRectObject *self, void *closure)
{
    return PyInt_FromLong (self->r.w);
}
```

I would still recommend using `width`/`height` instead of `w`/`h` for readability.