# Pygame: Are there virtual attributes for circle objects?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to build a little game project with Python3.7 and the Pygame Library.
So far I have made large use of Rect-Objects virtual attributes (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025688/whats-the-difference-between-the-width-and-w-attribute-of-a-pygame-rect-objec)).
Is there a chance to benefit from virtual attributes for Circle-Objects too? As an example: "circle.top", "circle.left", "circle.circumferencepoint". They would come in handy for collision detection logics. I've been searching around but, so far, have found nothing helpful.
Thanks

Comment: there should be special function to check collison between circles - it uses radius to check collision `R1+R2 > distance_between_centers` - they don't need top/left/etc. BUt you can always keep also `Rect` for to uses `top/left/etc.`

Comment: `Sprite` keeps position and size in `Rect` and uses it to check colision between circles [pygame.sprite.collide_circle](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle) - so you have both collision between circles and still you can get `rect.left`, `rect.top`, etc. You don't need special Circle-Object for this.

Comment: You confuse different things. [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is an object. But something like a `pygame.Circle` object does not exist. It is just possible to draw a circle by [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle). You would have to create your own `class Circle`.

Comment: Understood. I was actually confusing the two things. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

YYou are confusing different things. [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is an object. But there is no such thing as a *pygame.Circle* object. It is just possible to draw a circle with [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle). You would need to create your own *Circle* class.